# spacy creating one large doc vs. creating paragraph by paragraph

Tags: python, performance, spacy

I am using Spacy to get insights from texts and also creating my own custom pipeline for my particular needs.

It also happens that in a particular text it is important for me to now the number of paragraph.

Imaging I have a text like:

```
text="""this is a first paragraph. /n This is a second paragraph. /n And this might be the third paragraph"""
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
mydoc = nlp(text)
```

Is there any loss of accuracy in information extraction if instead I do:

```
text="""this is a first paragraph. /n This is a second paragraph. /n And this might be the third paragraph"""
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
docs = [nlp(paragraph) for paragraph in text.split("/n")]
```

Or put other ways, does Spacy performs better because there is more context when building a doc or not?

Comment: AFAIK, the "right"/intended way of doing it is to implement a custom component that makes paragraph spans accessible in a way that suits your application.

Comment: That's a good one but it's jot so that for creating a Span you first need to create the doc, so it's like a devils circle.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to whether context is useful is that it depends. There is no universal answer.

However, for the standard spaCy components, context is not useful beyond a couple of sentences, so if you have a very long document (like more than a page or two) you should break it up.

For individual paragraphs, there will often not be major differences between concatenating them or processing them individually.